# Nodejs, observe class fields for changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

Its possible to create direct proxy watchers for class properties in nodejs?

```
class User{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
        let pObject = new Proxy(this,{
            set: () => {
                console.log("something changed"); // should be called
                return true;
            }
        })
        Object.assign(this, pObject) // something like this?
    }
}



let user = new User("Mike");
user.name = "Jack"
```

Comment: Thank you guys. This what i needed. Cant add + to rep :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to observe setters on the instance? You can return the proxy itself:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    let pObject = new Proxy(this, {
      set: (obj, prop, value) => {
        console.log("something changed"); // should be called
        return Reflect.set(obj, prop,value)      // set the property
      }
    })
    return pObject
  }
}



let user = new User("Mike");
user.name = "Jack"
user.state = "Alaska"
console.log(user)
console.log(user instanceof User)
```

Answer (score 1):

Already answered by [Mark Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer), here was my take ( I am late by a few minutes to post this ) :

```
class User {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.UserProxy = {
            set(object, prop, value) {
                console.log('Object ', object);
                console.log('Prop ', prop);
                console.log('Value ', value);
                // Do whatever you wish to 
            }
        };
        return new Proxy(this, this.UserProxy);
    }
}

let user = new User('Mike');
user.name = 'Jack';
user.name = 'Falcon';
```

Answer (score 0):

**User Class:**

```
class User {
        constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.UserProxy = {
            set(object, prop, value) {
                console.log('Object ', object);
                console.log('Prop ', prop);
                console.log('Value ', value);
                return Reflect.set(object, prop, value) ;
            }
        };
        return new Proxy(this, this.UserProxy);
    }
}
```

**User Attribute:**

```
let user = new User('Mike');
user.name = 'Jack';
user.name = 'Falcon';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).